# Aster Database to Hadoop using Sqoop

Tags: teradata, sqoop

I am using the below syntax to read from Teradata Aster database Table transaction and load into Hadoop/Hive Table

I have added the below jar files in `/usr/iop/4.1.0.0/sqoop/lib` folder

```
terajdbc4.jar
tdgssconfig.jar
noarch-aster-jdbc-driver.jar
```

Syntax:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:ncluster://hostname.gm.com:2406/Database=test --username abcde --password test33  --table aqa.transaction
```

Error:

```
Warning: /usr/iop/4.1.0.0/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
16/12/14 15:38:49 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6_IBM_20
16/12/14 15:38:49 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/12/14 15:38:49 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string: jdbc:ncluster://hostname.gm.com:2406/Database=test
        at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:191)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.init(BaseSqoopTool.java:256)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.init(ImportTool.java:89)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:593)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `--connection-manager <class-name>` in your sqoop command if available for your RDBMS in sqoop.

Otherwise, add `--driver <driver-name>` in your sqoop command to use Generic connection manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with JDBC jar from Aster.

Here are some steps that I followed to create an external Hive table after importing an Aster table using Sqoop:

1. Download JDBC jar from https://aster-community.teradata.com/docs/DOC-2254
2. export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$PWD/noarch-aster-jdbc-driver.jar
3. sqoop import -D mapreduce.job.name="Sqoop Hive Import for Aster table tableName" --connect "jdbc:ncluster://X.X.X.X/database" --driver com.asterdata.ncluster.Driver --username "user1" --password "password" --query "select * from schema.table where \$CONDITIONS limit 10" --split-by col1 --as-avrodatafile --target-dir /tmp/aster/tableName
4. Create an external Hive table on target directory or replace avrodatafile with hive table options.